# Java: how declare an array and quickly fill its with data?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String st3[]=new String[]{"сто", "двести", "триста", "sdf", "sdfsd", "sdfsd"};
    System.out.println(st3[1]);
}
```

In second line Netbeans displays an error:

```
"non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context".
```

I know that the problem is in declaring the array. How to declare a STRING array and quickly fill it with data?

Sorry for stupid question and very bad english.

Thanks very much for answers, error resolved. :)

Comment: For more info see Arrays section of Java tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem isn't to do with declaring an array at all. You haven't shown enough code to show what really *is* wrong with it, but it's not those lines themselves. The array initialization is a little bit long-winded, but it's valid.

Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Which method are these lines in?

Here's a short but complete program which *does* work:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st3[]=new String[]{"x", "y", "z", "sdf", "sdfsd", "sdfsd"};
        System.out.println(st3[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to declare and fill in an array:

```
String[] st3 = {"сто", "двести", "триста", "sdf", "sdfsd", "sdfsd"};
```